# Paste value from PHP to JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, html

I try to paste a PHP `$value` to the JavaScript to show it but it fails to get the value.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    function here(elemento){
        alert (elemento);
    }
</script>

<body>
    <?php $value= 1?>
    <!--Al hace llamado a la función solo tienes que idicar el nombre del DIV entre parentesis -->
    <p><a href="#" onclick="here('.$value.')" title="">Mostrar / Ocultar</a></p>

    <div id="contenido_a_mostrar">
        <p>Este contenido tiene que mostrarse con el link</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

I try this `<p><a href="#" onclick="here('<? php echo $value; ?>')" title="">Mostrar / Ocultar</a></p>`

but the alert show me  this `<?php echo $value?>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script language="JavaScript">

function here(elemento){
    alert (elemento);
}

</script>
<a href="#" onclick="here('<?php echo $value?>')" title="">Mostrar / Ocultar</a>
```

You'll have to `echo` the value into the HTML

[docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php)

Answer (score 1):

```
onclick="here('<?php echo $value;?>')"
```

Answer (score 0):

To use PHP code, you will need to invoke the PHP part of the file using `<?php` again. In your case, the code's body should look like:

```
<body>
<?php $value = 1; ?>
<p><a href="#" onclick="here('<?php $value; ?>')" title="">Mostrar / Ocultar</a></p>
```

This way, it will be a PHP code getting executed when the HTML is prepared and `$value` will be concantenated into the HTML properly.